# Error when using BigQuery ML MODEL_TYPE='AUTOML_CLASSIFIER'

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-automl) and create an AutoML classifier model from BigQuery. The following is the code I'm using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `my_project.my_dataset.automl_20210214`
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE = 'AUTOML_CLASSIFIER', budget_hours=1.0, INPUT_LABEL_COLS=['target']) AS

SELECT
  * EXCEPT(row_number, user_id) -- Exclude unnecessary feature columns.
FROM `project_id.my_dataset.table_train`
;
```

The code runs for 3 min and throws then the following error.

```
An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 80038528
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For the feature columns with underscore in the beginning it should be returning a user visible error. For eg. it returns "For AutoML Tables training, column names cannot start with underscores. Invalid column name: _feature in query statement" for the following query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL
  `myproject.dataset.model` OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE = 'AUTOML_CLASSIFIER',
    budget_hours=1.0,
    INPUT_LABEL_COLS=['target']) AS
SELECT
  1.0 AS _feature,
  "True" AS target
```